# How to compare values generated in a for loop without using an array

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, comparison

Hello I am creating a program that asks a user how many rectangles they would like to input in the program. Then, I use this number in a `for` loop that loops while asking the user the name of each rectangle as well as the coordinates of 2 corners on the rectangle. In this `for` loop, after the user inputs all this data, I would like to compare these points to find which rectangle has the max/min area and perimeter without using an array. This is part of my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       process(s);
    }

    public static void process(Scanner s) {
       System.out.println("Please enter the number of rectangles as an integer");
        int rectnum;
       rectnum = s.nextInt();

       for(int i = 0; i<rectnum; i++){

       System.out.println("PLease enter the rectangle's name as a single letter");
       String rectname;
       rectname = s.next();

       System.out.println("Please enter the x value of one coordinate 
                                               of the rectangle" );
       int xcoor1;
       xcoor1 = s.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the y value of the same coorinate 
                                                         of the rectangle");

       int ycoor1;
       ycoor1 = s.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the x value of annother 
                                                 coordinate of the rectangle");

       int xcoor2;
       xcoor2 = s.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the y value of the same 
                                                 coordinate of the rectangle");
       int ycoor2;
       ycoor2 = s.nextInt();
      int Perim;
        Perim = 2 *(java.lang.Math.abs(ycoor1 - ycoor2)+
                        java.lang.Math.abs(xcoor1 - xcoor2));
        int Area;
        Area = java.lang.Math.abs((ycoor1 - ycoor2) * (xcoor1 - ycoor2));
        /*
         * ....
        */
 }}
```

Comment: Try creating max/min variables for area and perimeter outside the loop and update them whenever a new one is found.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an array? Do you need to rectangles outside of the process method, or just the min/max rectangles?

Comment: what kind of code would I use to update it? could you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: I just need the rectangles to calculate values of the attributes like perimeter and area and compare to other rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
int pMax=Integer.MIN_VALUE,pMin=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int aMax=Integer.MIN_VALUE,aMin=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

And inside your loop, after calculating the area and perimeter of the input rectangle, you can compare it to the existing maxes and mins, updating them as needed.

ie:

```
if(area<aMin)
    aMin=area;
if(area>aMax)
    aMax=area;
if(perim<pMin)
    pMin=perim;
if(perim>pMax)
    pMax=perim;
```

Comment: Ok, so put the first box before the loop in order to initialize the variables?

Comment: Yes, keep the declarations outside the for loop so that you can use them afterwards

Comment: ok, and should i keep the functions for calculating the min and max as is or rename the variables associated with them?

Comment: Change the variables in my test statements to what they are in your code, or change your code to match my test statements:both actions would be to the same effect.

Comment: ok, I did that. I will test it and let you know if this works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with a `Rectangle` [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)

```
public class Rectangle {
    private final char name;
    private final int x1;
    private final int x2;
    private final int y1;
    private final int y2;
    public Rectangle(char name, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s : (%d, %d) (%d, %d)",
            Character.toString(name), x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    // ...
}
```

And of course `...` can be whatever other methods you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called Rectangle that stores the relevant value, as well as the name of the rectangle.  Create 4 objects in the class and call them maxArea, minArea, maxPerimeter and minPerimeter.  As you loop through the user input, replace the relevant values of the objects as soon as you encounter a new max area, min area, min perimeter or max perimeter.

This approach has the advantage of being constant in its space requirement, regardless of the number of rectangles the user enters.